# Why doesn't scrollIntoView work in Vue 3 even though I'm able to get a reference to the element that I'm trying to scroll to

Tags: typescript, vue.js, vue-component, vuejs3

I have a Vue 3 component that I'm trying to setup as my navigation for a single page app. When the user clicks on an item I'd like for the page to scroll to the element that contains the content for that section.

The strange thing is that I'm able to get a reference to the div using `document.querySelector`. I'm able to log the div to the consol however when I try to call scrollIntoView on the div it doesn't do anything unless I wrap the `element.scrollIntoView` in a `setTimeout` function.

I'm sure this has something to do with the Vue component life cycle. I've tried wrapping my code in the `onMounted` function and that only makes my `scrollPageTo` function fall out of scope.

```
<template>
    <div id="navigation-view" class="navigation-bar bg-gradient-to-tr w-full mx-auto flex items-start py-4">
        <div class="w-full mx-auto text-right">
                <nav>
                    <a class="top-nav-item" href="#" v-on:click="scrollPageTo('home-view')">
                        <i class="fa fa-home fa-lg"></i> Home
                    </a>

                    <a class="top-nav-item" href="#" v-on:click="scrollPageTo('hello-view')">
                        <i class="fa fa-hands-helping fa-lg"></i> Hello
                    </a>

                    <a class="top-nav-item" href="#" v-on:click="scrollPageTo('contact-view')">
                        <i class="fa fa-envelope fa-lg"></i> Contact
                    </a>
                </nav>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="logo">
        <img src="/assets/img/615io-logo-wbg.png" alt="615io logo">
    </div>
</template>
<script lang="ts">
import {defineComponent, onMounted} from "vue";
export default defineComponent({
    setup() {

        const scrollPageTo = (navEl) => {
            console.log(`#${navEl}`);
            let element = document.querySelector(`#${navEl}`);
            console.log(element);
            element.scrollIntoView({behavior: 'smooth'});
        }

        return {
            scrollPageTo,
        }


    }
});
</script>
```

Comment: Hi, I'm also new to Vue 3 but this seems to be working fine. https://jsfiddle.net/r1xbej3d/

Comment: @User28 good example but this will not work if you use `a` instead of `button`, but if you you add the prevent modifier it works

Comment: Oh you're right I didn't notice that from the OP code use `a` tag.

Answer (score 4):

Add `prevent` modifier to the click event because this modifier prevent the default behavior which is the navigation to `#`:

```
v-on:click.prevent="scrollPageTo('home-view')"
```

**[LIVE DEMO](https://codesandbox.io/s/crazy-borg-5brot?file=/src/App.vue)**